# Typing an overloaded decorator wrapped in partial

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I am trying to get the typing of an overloaded decorator right that gets wrapped by `partial`:

```
from functools import partial
from typing import Any, Callable, Optional, Union, overload


AnyCallable = Callable[..., Any]


class Wrapped:
    def __init__(self, func: AnyCallable, foo: str, bar: bool) -> None:
        pass


@overload
def create_wrapped(foo: str, func: AnyCallable) -> Wrapped:
    ...


@overload
def create_wrapped(foo: str, *, bar: bool = ...) -> Callable[[AnyCallable], Wrapped]:
    ...


def create_wrapped(
    foo: str,
    func: Optional[AnyCallable] = None,
    *,
    bar: bool = True,
) -> Union[Wrapped, Callable[[AnyCallable], Wrapped]]:
    def wrapper(func_: AnyCallable) -> Wrapped:
        return Wrapped(func_, foo, bar)

    if func is None:
        return wrapper
    return wrapper(func)


baz = partial(create_wrapped, "baz")


@baz
def func_1() -> None:
    pass


@baz(bar=False)
def func_2() -> None:
    pass
```

The code is correct, but mypy gives

```
47: error: "Wrapped" not callable
```

which indicates that the actual argument types are lost when applying `partial`, since `@baz(bar=False)` should match the second overload as it's the same as `@create_wrapped("baz", bar=False)`, which does work without an issue.

I'm not sure how else I could annotate this, in fact I couldn't come up with any way to make mypy not complain about this, even if I was fine with not having proper types for the decorator since in that case, I'd get an `Untyped decorator makes function untyped` error.

Comment: `Wrapped` is not in fact `callable`. To make it compatible with `callable`, you have to declare `__call__` method.

Comment: That is not the issue. As I said, the code works correctly. If you look closely, you'll see that the second call does *not* return `Wrapped`. It returns a callable that returns `Wrapped`.

Comment: Alright, I see. The code is in fact correct, but it is **mypy** that incorrectly infers the partially applied function type. There is an issue for that in **mypy** github repository: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1484

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**mypy** does not currently correctly infer the type of a partially applied function: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1484.

You can work around it by casting the return of the `partial` call to a proper `Protocol`.

```py
from functools import partial
from typing import Any, Callable, Optional, Protocol, Union, overload, cast


AnyCallable = Callable[..., Any]


class Wrapped:
    def __init__(self, func: AnyCallable, foo: str, bar: bool) -> None:
        pass


@overload
def create_wrapped(foo: str, func: AnyCallable) -> Wrapped:
    ...


@overload
def create_wrapped(foo: str, *, bar: bool = ...) -> Callable[[AnyCallable], Wrapped]:
    ...


def create_wrapped(
    foo: str,
    func: Optional[AnyCallable] = None,
    *,
    bar: bool = True,
) -> Union[Wrapped, Callable[[AnyCallable], Wrapped]]:
    def wrapper(func_: AnyCallable) -> Wrapped:
        return Wrapped(func_, foo, bar)

    if func is None:
        return wrapper

    return wrapper(func)


class partial_create_wrapped(Protocol):
    @overload
    def __call__(self, *, bar: bool = ...) -> Callable[[AnyCallable], Wrapped]:
        ...

    @overload
    def __call__(self, func: AnyCallable) -> Wrapped:
        ...


baz = cast(partial_create_wrapped, partial(create_wrapped, "baz"))


@baz
def func_1() -> None:
    pass


@baz(bar=False)
def func_2() -> None:
    pass
```